# How I can replace colors with Imagemagick?

Tags: php, imagemagick, png

I need to replace violet and yellow colors with white.
I've tried to remove violet with this code:

```
convert image.png -fuzz 30% -fill white -opaque '#8f8aff' result.png
```

Before:

[image: before]

After:

[image: after]

Where is my mistake??

Comment: Your code that aims to replace violet works in my machine when using command line.

Comment: Maybe `convert thing.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill white -opaque "rgb(143,141,250)" -opaque "rgb(216,217,62)" result.png`

Comment: convert thing.jpg -fuzz 15% -fill white -opaque "rgb(143,141,250)" -opaque "rgb(216,217,62)" result.png - works fine! thanx!!!